# Newby learning Solidity - Parser Error

Tags: solidity, error, parser

I am getting this error when I try to compile

> Airlines.sol:49:5: ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'illegal' ➥
> public{

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;    
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED for non-open-source code.  Please see https://spdx.org for more information
    contract Airlines  {
    address chairperson;
    struct details{
        uint escrow; // deposit for payment settlement
        uint status;
        uint hashOfDetails;
    }
    
    mapping (address=>details) public balanceDetails;
    mapping (address=>uint) membership;
    
    // modifiers or rules
    modifier onlyChairperson{
        require(msg.sender==chairperson);
        _;
    }
    modifier onlyMember{
        require(membership[msg.sender]==1);
        _;
    }
    
    // constructor function
    constructor () public payable  {
      
        chairperson=msg.sender;
        membership[msg.sender]=1; // automatically registered
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].escrow = msg.value;
    }
    
    function register ( ) public payable{
        
        address AirlineA = msg.sender;
        membership[AirlineA]=1;
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].escrow = msg.value;
    }
        
   function unregister (address payable AirlineZ) onlyChairperson public {
        if(chairperson!=msg.sender){
            revert(); }
        membership[AirlineZ]=0;
        // return escrow to leaving airline: verify other conditions 
        AirlineZ.transfer(balanceDetails[AirlineZ].escrow);
        balanceDetails[AirlineZ].escrow = 0; 
    }
    
    function request(address toAirline, uint hashOfDetails) onlyMember
    ➥ public{
        if(membership[toAirline]!=1){
            revert(); }
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].status=0;
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].hashOfDetails = hashOfDetails;
    }
    
    function  response(address fromAirline, uint hashOfDetails, uint done) 
                               onlyMember public{
      
        if(membership[fromAirline]!=1){
            revert();  }
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].status=done;
        balanceDetails[fromAirline].hashOfDetails = hashOfDetails;
    }
    
    
function settlePayment  (address payable toAirline) onlyMember payable     
                                       public{
        address fromAirline=msg.sender;
        uint amt = msg.value; 
        balanceDetails[toAirline].escrow = balanceDetails[toAirline].escrow 
                                                   + amt;
        balanceDetails[fromAirline].escrow =      
                balanceDetails[fromAirline].escrow - amt;
       
       // amt subtracted from msg.sender and given to toAirline
        toAirline.transfer(amt
```

Comment: Please can you insert smart contract's code into a single code sample section?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set signature of a method in a single line. In your code, change your `request()` function with this:

```
function request(address toAirline, uint hashOfDetails) onlyMember public{
        if(membership[toAirline]!=1){
            revert(); }
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].status=0;
        balanceDetails[msg.sender].hashOfDetails = hashOfDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be resolved if you remove `➥` from the code.

Anyway, I would recommend for you go through [the style guide for Solidity coding](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/style-guide.html).
It would probably make it easier for you to find issues in future, make code more readable and maintainable.